# Set public property of user control on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, properties, user-controls, public

I have a user control on a page. The user control has a public property on it that I need to set after a button click. How do you do this?
It appears that the control is rendered before the button click event fires, so setting the property has no effect.

Page:
    <%@ Register src="Email.ascx" tagname="Email" tagprefix="uc2" %>

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
        EmailList.IsEditable = false;
}

protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EmailList.IsEditable = true;
}
```

User Control:
    public bool IsEditable { get; set; }

The public property gets set correctly when I set it in the page load event, but not on the button click.
The button is used to change the form from read-only to edit mode. Is there a way to set a public property in the button click event? If so, how?

Comment: What does IsEditable do in the "set" implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property is getting set just fine. The problem is where in your usercontrol you set it's controls to readonly/enabled.

If you want to be able to affect how the usercontrol gets rendered, you must do the logic where you're setting the readonly/enabled properties of the subcontrols in the `Page_PreRender` event of the usercontrol. This event is executed after the buttonclick events.

A must read on msdn: [the page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#lifecycle_events). You'll notice the control events get processed after `Page_Load` and before `Page_LoadComplete`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment. That worked great for me. I just set a variable in the button click event and use it in the PagePreRender method and everything works fine!

Comment: @JimShaffer glad it works for you :). Make sure to read the page lifecycle though, it's incredibly informative for when you're new to ASP.net